# ngIf condition on mat-option is not getting executed

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ng-if, mat-select, mat-option

I have 2 mat-options.
1 for loading items from backend and another to display None.

```
<mat-form-field id="Dropdown">
    <mat-select id="ddlabel" placeholder="{{'DDLabel' | translate}}" [(value)]="selecteditem" (selectionChange)="changeitem($event)">
      <mat-option class="items-toload" [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of dditems">{{ item }}</mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngIf="isitemSelected()" class="items-toload">{{'ItemNone'  | translate}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I would want to display None(second mat-option) only when item (from first mat-option) is selected.

```
isitemSelected() {
    if (this.selecteditem != '') {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

But this function is not getting called, so always None option is availble in the UI.
please help in understanding how this is not called.

I have added an alert to `isitemselected()` and noticed that this is not being called.
I tried using variable and setting that to true when item is selected in `changeitem($event)`, that is always not working.

Comment: What do you want? You need to remove selected option from the list?

Comment: Have you checked in your dditems variable has proper data?

Comment: As mentioned in the question I want to display None(second mat-option) only when item (from first mat-option) is selected.

Comment: yes dditems have no issue, it is loading. Issue here is isSelectedItem() is not getting called. ngIf condition is not executed

Comment: Try to change this condition if(this.selecteditem != '') to if(this.selecteditem)

Comment: Or else put condition directly on HTML side like *ngIf="selecteditem && selecteditem != ''"

Comment: I have added window.alert in isSelectedItem(), this function is never being called

Comment: Put condition in HTML only you don't need to call function in *ngIf condition

Comment: I have tried that as well *ngIf="(selectedItem != '')" did not work

Comment: Then you need to add one option in **dditems** data from typescript when selectionChange event fired.

Comment: Make sure you will put same condition which is in bold in this comment ***ngIf="selecteditem && selecteditem != ''"**

Comment: yes this worked adding both conditions. thankyou so much. please add it as an answer

Comment: Thanks for quick response from your side as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call function in ***ngIf** condition. Please add below condition in your html directly.

***ngIf="selecteditem && selecteditem != ''"**

```
<mat-option *ngIf="selecteditem && selecteditem != ''" class="items-toload">{{'ItemNone'  | translate}}</mat-option>
```